# exec /usr/local/openjdk-21/bin/java: exec format error

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have a Jenkins server installed on aarch64 Ubuntu server. When I deploy a docker image on a x86 kubernetes cluster I get error:

```
exec /usr/local/openjdk-21/bin/java: exec format error
```

I use this Docker file:

```
# Use a Java runtime as the base image
FROM openjdk:21-slim-buster

VOLUME /tmp

# Copy the built JAR file into the container
ADD build/libs/mockup.jar mockup.jar

# Expose the default port for the app
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the app when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "mockup.jar"]
```

Looks like Jenkins Jenkins compiles by default always the image for aarch64 architecture. Is there some solution?

Comment: The processor architecture of your CI system and deployment environment need to match.  The ARM hosts can't run x86 binaries, and _vice versa_.  Maybe this specific Dockerfile that doesn't `RUN` anything could be successfully built on a wrong-arrchitecture platform, but in general, not without some sort of emulation system or replacing the hardware to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, both Docker and Podman support multi-platform builds:

- Docker documentation: [Multi-platform images](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/)
- RedHat Developers blog: [How to build multi-architecture container images](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2023/11/03/how-build-multi-architecture-container-images#understanding_multi_architecture_containers)

You can use `--platform=linux/386` or any desired target platforms when you build your image (AFAIR it works even without `buildx`).

You can also use the same in `FROM` instruction of your Dockerfile.